# List the categories under custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem here, I registered a custom post type and I named it 'recipe'
then I created a custom taxonomy under the post type, I named it 'recipe category'. Now I want to display the of categories under that custom taxonomy, but unfortunately I have no luck.

I tried this code

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'recipecategory';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

but it displays nothing, what's wrong with my code? did I missed something. 
Almost forgot to mention, I am using the plugin [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

Comment: Does it output empty markup (li,a), or absolutely nothing?

Comment: @vancoder , yes absolutely nothing.. I don't know why.. 
here's the
[image](http://i.imgur.com/kifLtpY.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can only be one of the following:

1. Your taxonomy "recipecategory" does not exist.
2. Your taxonomy has no terms.
3. None of your recipecategory terms have any posts. In this case, make the following change:

`$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));`

This should work as it will override the default setting, which is to ignore empty terms.

```
 foreach($tax_terms as $term_single) {      
         $term_single->slug;  
         $term_single->name;        
 }
```

Comment: thanks @vancoder, I thought that its possible to display the categories under my custom taxonomy without creating a posts using the categories. Now I know, thank you so much its a relief. :)